# How to expand the boot size?

Tags: upgrade

Trying to upgrade to 18.04 from 16.04, no free space in boot partition. Tried to expand boot size according some instructions searched from the web but failed. See attached Gparted report and advise how to resize the boot.

[image]

Comment: The little key icon between the  "Partition" and "Name" columns shows that the partition is mounted, and cannot be changed. You need to boot from a Live CD/USB, then you can adjust your partitions.